# Quemar la etiqueta [frontend]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Las estadisticas de uso dicen que es una etiqueta con 16 preguntas.

- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [ingenieria-del-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingenieria-del-software)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [kendoui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kendoui)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [ionic2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- 2 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [jwt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt)
- 6 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- 1 con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) y [materialize](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize)

Como se ve, es una meta etiqueta, que se usa indiscriminadamente. Es más, hay preguntas que no están directamente relacionadas a cómo hacer un frontend, y si la etiqueta fuera pura sobre diseño de interfaces de usuarios, igual dependería de un lenguaje (ya que no es lo mismo diseñar para web, para telefono, para escritorio, y no es lo mismo el diseño en c#, java o delphi).

Ejemplos:

[¿Como configurar rutas de frontend con AngularJS y un servidor ExpressJS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63645/como-configurar-rutas-de-frontend-con-angularjs-y-un-servidor-expressjs)

[Angular ui-select not array filter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79379/angular-ui-select-not-array-filter)

[Abrir documento, editar y al cerrar llamar a función callback](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108246/abrir-documento-editar-y-al-cerrar-llamar-a-funci%c3%b3n-callback)

[Consumir json desde backend php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56707/consumir-json-desde-backend-php)

[Concatenar entero y cadena en un temaplate de Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53530/concatenar-entero-y-cadena-en-un-temaplate-de-django)

[¿Qué significa llevar un proyecto a ''producción''?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50670/qu%c3%a9-significa-llevar-un-proyecto-a-producci%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En 24 horas esta etiqueta no existirá. Voy a marcar esta petición como ya completada.

Comment: Ok cuando este lista acepto la respuesta

Comment: Pero Juan, solamente la eliminaste? No la veo en la lista negra. En el futuro puede volver a aparecer.